# How to call a function automatically on document ready event in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I m having following Code in which this code executes when i click a anchor tag named msgup

```
    $("#msgup").bar({
        color : '#1E90FF',
        background_color : '#FFFFFF',
        removebutton     : false,
        message : 'Your profile customization has been saved!',
        time: 4000

});
```

But I want to do this thing automatically when page loads , so what is required to achieve such workflow?

Actually i m using jBar plugin to show stackoverflow type notifications at top of the page.

Comment: i m following this tutorial http://tympanus.net/Development/jbar/  the code that executes after clicking the back buttons i want to execute the same code just after dom is ready.

Comment: most of the people I guess misunderstood what the OP wants... or is it just me. [jBar](http://tympanus.net/Development/jbar/) <-- in there, the button needs to be "clicked" before the message appear. and for me the OP does not want that. The OP wanted it to appear without clicking. Correct me if I'm wrong. :D

Comment: yes Reigel i want that without click just after page loads or DOM ready

Comment: do you actually have an anchor with the **ID** msgup on that page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this using following code

```
$(document).ready(function()
{

     $("<div id='notify'></div>").prependTo('body').hide();
}
```

Style defined in header:

```
<style>
#notify{

       position:fixed;
           top: 21%; 
        left: 40%;
       width: 20%;
        height:4%;
        text-align:center;
            text-weight:bold;
           font-size:20px;
         background-color:YELLOW;
          color:BLUE;
            padding:3px;
           z-index:9999;
}

</style>
```

and dynamically call this function using following echo statement in PHP

```
echo "<script> setTimeout(function(){
            $('#notify').html('Updated Successfully !').slideDown(2000);
 },0);
     </script>";
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#msgup").bar({
        color : '#1E90FF',
        background_color : '#FFFFFF',
        removebutton     : false,
        message : 'Your profile customization has been saved!',
        time: 4000

    }).click(); // call click right away...
 });
```

Comment: i have tried above code and this $(document).ready(function() {  click(); });  but nothing happens

Answer (score 1):

Put the code into a function, and then run that function in your jquery document ready:

```
function msgup_bar(){
$("#msgup").bar({
        color : '#1E90FF',
        background_color : '#FFFFFF',
        removebutton     : false,
        message : 'Your profile customization has been saved!',
        time: 4000

});
}

$(document).ready(function() {
   msqup_bar();
 });
```

http://www.learningjquery.com/2006/09/introducing-document-ready

Comment: Thanks for suggestion Curt, but i m not having any id named #msgup in my page will this code works ?

Comment: I have checked Code is not running . I think i can't explain u fully what i want to do.

Comment: You need to create div with id msgup to your website or you can create with jQuery using .append(), .html() etc.

Comment: @Curt, just so you know, you've got an extra function there that you don't need. Instead of passing an anonymous function to ready, and inside that function calling the msqup_bar(), you can pass msqup_bar directly to .ready, since it is already a no parameter function.

Comment: @Josh Cheers Josh, I just prefer to not put any actual code into the document ready function so that it's neater :)

Comment: @Curt, I think you may have misunderstood me. I think the document ready function should look like this: $(document).ready(msqup_bar); One less creation of an anonymous function inside the ready function.

Comment: @Josh - Ooh I see what you mean now! that makes sense! Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I *think* you are looking for [LiveQuery jquery plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery).

> Live Query utilizes the power of
>   jQuery selectors by binding events or
>   firing callbacks for matched elements
>   auto-magically, even after the page
>   has been loaded and the DOM updated.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin is only built to be used by clicking on an element, there is no support for showing a bar without a click event.

Reigel's suggestion to call `click` immediately should work, but then you have to include that element in the page so that the plugin has something to hook up the events to.

Answer (score 0):

Abhishek, your code seems it uses some jquery plugin, which will do something with the element having id msgup, you should have element having id msgup. Create element having id msgup and modify code,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//you code here
})
```